# Semantic ui dropdown с флагами в input (React js)

Tags: reactjs, input, semantic-ui

Всем привет, хочу сделать input для ввода телефона с выбором начала номера и флагом, вот пример

[image: пример]

Делаю так

```
import React from "react";
import { Dropdown, Input } from "semantic-ui-react";
import countries from "./common";

const PhoneInput = () => (
    <div>
        <Input
            action={
                <Dropdown
                    left="true"
                    button
                    basic
                    floating
                    defaultValue="af"
                    options={countries}
                />
            }
            actionPosition={"left"}
            placeholder="Phone"
        />
    </div>
);
export default PhoneInput;
```

В файле common массив такого типа

`{ text: "Afghanistan +540", flag: "af", value: "af", key: "af" }`

В результате выходит

[image: что получилось]

Как сделать так что бы при выборе отображался не текст а флаг?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению то что Вы пытаетесь сделать на данный момент невозможно. [Здесь](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/2296#issuecomment-345090336) можно посмотреть ответ создателя SemanticUI по этому поводу.

> `text` Displayed in the Dropdown Input after the item is made active, should be a string.

*(перевод): `text` отображается в инпуте дропдауна после того как элемент списка был выбран, и должен быть строкой*

> Dropdown Item `content` only appears in the Menu, not in the Input once made active.

*(перевод): `content` отображается только в выпадающем списке, и не отображается в поле инпута после выбора*